# UE4: Conver String HEX Color to RGB or RBGA in Blueprint

Tags: colors, hex, rgb, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

How to convert HEX Color String to RGB or RBGA in Unreal Engine's Blueprint. For example: #f0f8ff to 240/248/255 RGB vector.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Blueprint API does not support Hex to RGB or RGB to Hex, [but the regular FColor struct does](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FColor/FromHex/index.html), I'd suggest, you write yourself a wrapper for it in a [UBlueprintFunctionLibrary](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Kismet/UBlueprintFunctionLibrary/index.html).

I won't go into detail how to create one of these libraries, since you can find an easy tutorial in the [Unreal Wiki](https://unrealcommunity.wiki/blueprint-function-library-create-your-own-to-share-with-others-k0hmtysn). However, I may give you the code that will hopefully work:

part of the header:

```
/** Converts hex string to color. Supports formats RGB, RRGGBB, RRGGBBAA, RGB, #RRGGBB, #RRGGBBAA */
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="YourFunctionLibrary")
static FColor HexToColor(FString HexString);

/** Converts color to hex string */
UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category="YourFunctionLibrary")
static FString ColorToHex(FColor Color);
```

part of the compilation unit:

```
FColor YourFunctionLibrary::HexToColor(FString HexString)
{
    return FColor::FromHex(HexString);
}

FString YourFunctionLibrary::ColorToHex(FColor Color)
{
    return Color.ToHex();
}
```

Haven't tried it yet, but hope it works!

Comment: Yep, yesterday I ended up with the same solution as I didn't find anything built-in. I used a pure function code of FromHex from the color.cpp, that is located here: **C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Math** as I needed to extend it to also convert predefault color values like White etc. Thank you for the suggestion, I will accept it as the answer. If someone will use this code, please note that the second function in Max's code should return FString instead of FColor. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question while building an editor utility and found another option that worked out well. This utilizes a python command.

Here's what I've done:
https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/syz1siaw/

It's not the most elegant, but it's fun!

[image]